# Form group validation in angular

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

how to validate a `form group control` with code length which has decimal fields
my code like:

```
this.control = new FormControl(val, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(items.CodeLength)]);
```

but for controls with decimal value what validation should given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following RegExp validates any number with desired maxDecimalDigits.
One "special" thing about this one is, that it validates numbers with dot AND comma as decimal separators ([.,]?)

```
^.\\d*[.,]?\\d{0,' + maxDecimalDigits + '}?$
```

To use any RegExp, use Validators.pattern(YourRegExp) or create your own validatorFn using RegExp

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `max`(with limit) inspite of `maxlength`

```
this.control = new FormControl( val, 
   [Validators.required, Validators.max(9999999)]
);
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/model-driven-forms-mue94x?file=app/app.component.ts)